# WiFi CSMA mechanisms (CD/CA)

Tags: wifi

Is CSMA/CA (Collision Avoidance) mechanism active in WiFi networks by default (instead of CSMA/CD Collision Detection) or it has to be enabled by setting RTC/CTS threshold lower than packet size (2347bytes)? If it has not been activated by default, should one set it manually on AP (router) and all nodes (computers) manually?

Answer (score 0):

CSMA/CA is by default activted in the wireless driver.